# Good online C++ syntax reference?

Tags: c++, syntax

Do you know of a precise and concise online C++ syntax reference?
Please provide the link...

Comment: Here a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ for the library.

Try http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/ for the Final Draft International Standard for C++98.

Try http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf for the Working Draft Standard for C++0X.

Comment: This is a good C++ **Library** reference.  I need one for **Syntax**

Comment: Note: This site isn't entirely accurate, or at least the reference for istream::sync() (cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/…) is not standards-compliant, as I discovered yesterday while working on a user input problem. Caveat programmer?

Answer (score 18):

[cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/)

Microsoft specific [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bstk3k5.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/

Answer (score 4):

Given the complexity of C++, I don't think a concise C++ syntax reference is possible. :)  For not-so-concise references look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/

Answer (score 3):

My favourite is definetly http://www.grepdocs.com/ because it provides other languages too but for specific c++ reference, i head to http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/

Answer (score 2):

http://cplusplus.com/ is a good online reference for C/C++, I'm not sure if this is what you are after.

It has very good coverage of std library.

Comment: Always may first port of call

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch.  I use these pretty regularly.

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/)